# Menu Bar not going in the centre of the page, i have tried everything

Tags: css

For some reason the following code won't center on the page, even when I have typed many different codes in.

Here is the code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#nav {
font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter",       Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
margin: 0 0 3em 0;
padding: 10px 50%;
list-style: none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display: inline-block;
}
#nav li {
float: left;
}
#nav li a {
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
display:inline-block;
font-size:18px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
color:#00BFFF;
}
#header {
margin-top: 0;
width:100%;
height:150px;
background-color:#09F;
}
```

Please bear in mind that the nav bar is inside the header.

Comment: Please provide your code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It's not very polite to ask someone you don't know to DO IT ASAP, for free! Buy yourself a programmer!

Comment: One very handy way of debugging this sort of thing is to use Chrome or Firefox and use the developer tools to see, and even edit, the CSS for the element in question.

In Chrome, go to the page in question, then right click (control-click) and select Inspect Element.  This will show you, on the left, all the CSS which applies to that element, including anything which has been overridden by another style.  You can also click in that area and insert new CSS directives; this sort of direct editing is even faster than the usual edit/browser-reload cycle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GWCnf/1/ sorry to be rude, but i just need this website done really quickly

Comment: i want the menu bar centered horizontally please

Comment: @user2163073 Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't *demand* that the community does *anything* for you. We're here to help you, within reasonable efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GWCnf/6/)

You just need to remove the display property on the `<ul>` and give it a width. I also removed the padding that was on the list.

Comment: How? Lol im so new to this

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
#nav {
font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter",           Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
margin: 0 auto 3em;
width: XXpx
padding: 10px 50%;
list-style: none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display: inline-block;
}
```

and define the width

Edit:

```
function onload() {
document.getElementById("nav").style.marginLeft = Math.round(document.getElementById("nav").offsetWidth/2)+"px";}
```

Comment: for some reason, it is still not going to the middle, its sticking to the left

Comment: i want the menu bar centered horizontally please